# How to select Discord dropdown option using selenium python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-rc

I have just started working with Selenium and practicing different automations using it. I am attempting to type "/bump" in the chat and select the first option that appears. I have tried using different solutions, such as "By.id" and "By.xpath," but so far, none of them have worked for me.

This is how it looks like.

[image]

Here is my current working Python code:

```
url = "<channel url>"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Fahad\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

# Open the website in the browser
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
input_ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, r'//div[@role="textbox"]').send_keys("/bump")
time.sleep(5)
```

Now this was the last solution I was using for selecting that option but its not working either.

```
# Move the mouse to a specific pixel (e.g. x=100, y=200)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_by_offset(585, 602)

# Click the mouse at the current position
actions.click()
actions.perform()
time.sleep(5)
```

How to accomplish this task?

class names and HTML code structure of the Discord dropdown:

```html
  <div role="listbox" class="listItems-6eZzQ1" style="inset: 0px 8px;"><div class="clickable-2V8YKY itemWrapper-CeTtIp autocompleteRowVertical-EA9dCg autocompleteRow-14iwvH" role="option" data-list-item-id="channel-autocomplete___0" tabindex="-1" id="autocomplete-0" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true"><div class="base-2v-uc0"><div class="wrapper-1IOU8a"><div channel="[object Object]" class="wrapper-3t15Cn image-1a_IXB"><svg width="32" height="32" class="svg-lIB-lq mask-3pLFcz" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="32" height="32" overflow="visible" mask="url(#svg-mask-avatar-default)"><img alt="" class="icon-28xrhD" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/302050872383242240/67342a774a9f2d20d62bfc8553bb98e0.webp?size=32" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></foreignObject></svg></div><div class="infoWrapper-33i2RS"><div class="usageWrapper-2eaALZ"><div class="text-md-normal-2rFCH3 title-158kHv autocompleteRowHeading-3EcwU6" data-text-variant="text-md/normal" style="color: var(--interactive-active);">/bump</div></div><div class="text-xs-normal-3O7EaX description-1T7FK8 autocompleteRowSubheading-6CMP2P" data-text-variant="text-xs/normal" style="color: var(--interactive-normal);">Pushes your server to the top of all your server's tags and the front page</div></div><div class="text-xs-normal-3O7EaX source-3HVB4H autocompleteRowContentSecondary-Oobh2b" data-text-variant="text-xs/normal" style="color: var(--interactive-normal);">DISBOARD</div></div></div></div><div class="clickable-2V8YKY itemWrapper-CeTtIp autocompleteRowVertical-EA9dCg autocompleteRow-14iwvH" role="option" data-list-item-id="channel-autocomplete___1" tabindex="-1" id="autocomplete-1" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><div class="base-2v-uc0"><div class="wrapper-1IOU8a"><div channel="[object Object]" class="wrapper-3t15Cn image-1a_IXB"><svg width="32" height="32" class="svg-lIB-lq mask-3pLFcz" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="32" height="32" overflow="visible" mask="url(#svg-mask-avatar-default)"><img alt="" class="icon-28xrhD" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/476259371912003597/dfecd897bfe9a05619470338ea3a3cd4.webp?size=32" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></foreignObject></svg></div><div class="infoWrapper-33i2RS"><div class="usageWrapper-2eaALZ"><div class="text-md-normal-2rFCH3 title-158kHv autocompleteRowHeading-3EcwU6" data-text-variant="text-md/normal" style="color: var(--interactive-active);">/bump</div></div><div class="text-xs-normal-3O7EaX description-1T7FK8 autocompleteRowSubheading-6CMP2P" data-text-variant="text-xs/normal" style="color: var(--interactive-normal);">Get information on how to bump your server.</div></div><div class="text-xs-normal-3O7EaX source-3HVB4H autocompleteRowContentSecondary-Oobh2b" data-text-variant="text-xs/normal" style="color: var(--interactive-normal);">Discord.Me</div></div></div></div></div>
```

```
<div role="listbox" class="listItems-6eZzQ1" style="inset: 0px 8px;"><div class="clickable-2V8YKY itemWrapper-CeTtIp autocompleteRowVertical-EA9dCg autocompleteRow-14iwvH" role="option" data-list-item-id="channel-autocomplete___0" tabindex="-1" id="autocomplete-0" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true"><div class="base-2v-uc0"><div class="wrapper-1IOU8a"><div channel="[object Object]" class="wrapper-3t15Cn image-1a_IXB"><svg width="32" height="32" class="svg-lIB-lq mask-3pLFcz" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="32" height="32" overflow="visible" mask="url(#svg-mask-avatar-default)"><img alt="" class="icon-28xrhD" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/302050872383242240/67342a774a9f2d20d62bfc8553bb98e0.webp?size=32" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></foreignObject></svg></div><div class="infoWrapper-33i2RS"><div class="usageWrapper-2eaALZ"><div class="text-md-normal-2rFCH3 title-158kHv autocompleteRowHeading-3EcwU6" data-text-variant="text-md/normal" style="color: var(--interactive-active);">/bump</div></div><div class="text-xs-normal-3O7EaX description-1T7FK8 autocompleteRowSubheading-6CMP2P" data-text-variant="text-xs/normal" style="color: var(--interactive-normal);">Pushes your server to the top of all your server's tags and the front page</div></div><div class="text-xs-normal-3O7EaX source-3HVB4H autocompleteRowContentSecondary-Oobh2b" data-text-variant="text-xs/normal" style="color: var(--interactive-normal);">DISBOARD</div></div></div></div><div class="clickable-2V8YKY itemWrapper-CeTtIp autocompleteRowVertical-EA9dCg autocompleteRow-14iwvH" role="option" data-list-item-id="channel-autocomplete___1" tabindex="-1" id="autocomplete-1" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><div class="base-2v-uc0"><div class="wrapper-1IOU8a"><div channel="[object Object]" class="wrapper-3t15Cn image-1a_IXB"><svg width="32" height="32" class="svg-lIB-lq mask-3pLFcz" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="32" height="32" overflow="visible" mask="url(#svg-mask-avatar-default)"><img alt="" class="icon-28xrhD" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/476259371912003597/dfecd897bfe9a05619470338ea3a3cd4.webp?size=32" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></foreignObject></svg></div><div class="infoWrapper-33i2RS"><div class="usageWrapper-2eaALZ"><div class="text-md-normal-2rFCH3 title-158kHv autocompleteRowHeading-3EcwU6" data-text-variant="text-md/normal" style="color: var(--interactive-active);">/bump</div></div><div class="text-xs-normal-3O7EaX description-1T7FK8 autocompleteRowSubheading-6CMP2P" data-text-variant="text-xs/normal" style="color: var(--interactive-normal);">Get information on how to bump your server.</div></div><div class="text-xs-normal-3O7EaX source-3HVB4H autocompleteRowContentSecondary-Oobh2b" data-text-variant="text-xs/normal" style="color: var(--interactive-normal);">Discord.Me</div></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code with explicit waits and using click and was able to Select the option, I don't have bump option on the server i tested with so I assume the text is `/bump` but you can correct the locator if needed  below

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#driver setup and login steps here for discord

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# Wait for the textbox to be visible

textbox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@role="textbox"]')))

# Enter text in the textbox
textbox.send_keys("/bump")


# Find the "kick" element and click it
kick_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@role="listbox"]//div[text()="/bump"]')))
kick_element.click()
```